# Android add the special item in the List View by the SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-adapter

I have the one requirement to add the special item in the listview, which fully differnt with the others, and this is add dynamicly(when the user enter the special text) . and the listview
used the SimpleCursorAdapter to show the custom item.
and this adapter:
public class TweetAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements FilterQueryProvider

has no addItem() function, and the getView() just call super() function.
so I hava no idea about it.
could you help me about this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

CursorAdapter is not modifiable as such, so you wont be able to add custom elements at runtime and change the listView. You will need to use a MatrixCursor which is a modifiable form of Adapter. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html 
First, Make a matrix cursor from your existing cursoradapter, and use this matrixcursor as the data source. It is a mutable cursor, so you add rows whenever you want.

Comment: Yes, this can make me add the row to the cursoradapter, can I modify the special layout for the special row by the MatrixCursor?

Comment: yes, in the getVIew() of the adapter, look at the data you are getting adapter.get(position) or something. If it is  the special data, inflate and assign the special layout

Comment: Hi Akhil, from your suggestion, I try do the MatrixCursor on this problem, but i get into trouble:
how can i add the matrix cursor by the exist cursoradapter,
normally i want to cursoradapter have the add function, but it didn't
,and i search about this, all the example about matrix cursor, all is 
use the matrix cursor construct the adpater, not add maxtrix cursor in the adpater, can you help me? Thanks

Comment: From your database cursor, create a MatrixCursor, Then pass the matrix cursor as the cursor for CursorAdapter. Rest is the same as you would normally do. MatrixCursor just allowed ou to add some extra rows.

Comment: Like this?    
clCursor = new MatrixCursor(matrixCols);
startManagingCursor(clCursor);
if(contacts != null){
        for (Contact contact : contacts) {          
            clCursor.addRow(new Object[] { contact.id, contact.name, contact.description, contact.icon });
        }
    }
    adapterList = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.contactlist, clCursor, menuCols, toWhatId); 
    //in this line futureTask starts

    contactList.setAdapter(adapterList);